# Monte Carlo Estimates from Different distributions for $\theta = \int_{0}^1 \sin(x) dx$

Tags: r, monte-carlo

> Monte Carlo Estimates from Different distributions for $\theta = \int_{0}^1 \sin(x) dx$

So I understand that a monte carlo estimate for this integral should look like this $\hat\theta = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m sin(x_i)$, where $x_i \sim U(0,1)$

And in R I can see this works:

```
> m = 10^4
> x <- runif(m)
> theta.hat = mean(sin(x))
> cat(paste("Theta.hat = ", round(theta.hat, digits = 5)))
Theta.hat =  0.46435
```

Which is very close to the true value $1-\cos(1)\approx0.45969$

But I should also be able to estimate this by sampling from another distribution as well, say $Exp(1)$ where $f(x)=e^{-x}$

Since $\theta = \int_{0}^1 \frac{\sin(x)}{e^{-x}}\cdot e^{-x} dx= E(\frac{\sin(x)}{e^{-x}})$

Which I should have this estimator $\hat\theta = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m I(x_i<1) \frac{\sin(x_i)}{e^{-x_i}}$ with $x_i\sim Exp(1)$

When I try to do this in R however:

```
> m = 10^4
> accept = c()
> x <- rexp(m, rate = 1)
> for (i in x){
+   if(i<= 1){
+     accept=c(accept,(sin(i)/exp(-i)))
+   }
+ }
> mean(accept)
[1] 0.7255409
```

I get something that's significantly different from the actual value. I'm not sure what exactly it is that I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code in the latter case is taking the mean only over the cases where $x_i < 1$, which is incorrect.  As in your equation, you need to take the mean over *all* the simulations.  To do this, just replace `mean(accept)` with `sum(accept)/m` and you'll get a reasonable estimate.

**A few other coding tips:** You are presently working in *Circle 2 of hell* in the [R inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) --- it is better to pre-construct your vectors to the desired length and then populate them rather than growing them element-by-element in this manner.  Also, always [set your seed](http://127.0.0.1:15594/library/base/html/Random.html) for reproducibility when doing simulations involving PRNGs.  Here is a better way to code the latter simulation:

```
#Generate estimator via importance sampling
m <- 10^4
set.seed(1)
x <- rexp(m, rate = 1)
SIM <- rep(0, m)
for (i in 1:m) { 
  if (x[i] < 1) {
    SIM[i] <- sin(x[i])/exp(-x[i]) } }

#Compare estimator to known value
THETA     <- 1-cos(1)
THETA.HAT <- mean(SIM)

THETA
[1] 0.4596977

THETA.HAT
[1] 0.4583018
```

Comment: Yes thanks. I actually just realized this myself when I decided to check the length of my accept variable.